# Sometimes the program runs fine and sometimes program doesn't do anything

Tags: java, arrays, bubble-sort

I am trying to get a program to make 2 arrays of random numbers and then use the bubble method to sort them so later I can easily pick out the 3 middle numbers. When I retarded eclipse and ran it for the first time, but whenever I try to run it again the console displayed nothing, and I assume the program is still running because I have the option to terminated.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class DiversCalc {
    public static void main(String[] args){

    int[] Diver1 = new int[7];
    int[] Diver2 = new int[7];

    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int positionInArray = 0; positionInArray < Diver1.length; 
        positionInArray++) {
       int diverScore1 = rand.nextInt(10);
       Diver1[positionInArray] = diverScore1;
    }

    for (int positionInArray2 = 0; positionInArray2 < Diver2.length; 
        positionInArray2++) {
       int diverScore1 = rand.nextInt(10);
       Diver2[positionInArray2] = diverScore1;
    }

    int temp = 0;

    boolean checker = false;
    boolean checker2 = false;

    while(checker==false){
       checker=true;

       for(int positionCheck1 = 0; positionCheck1 < Diver1.length-1; 
           positionCheck1++){

          if(Diver1[positionCheck1] > Diver1[positionCheck1+1]){

              temp = Diver1[positionCheck1+1];

              Diver1[positionCheck1+1] = Diver1[positionCheck1];

              Diver1[1] = temp;

              checker=false; 

           }
       }
    }

    while(checker2==false){
       checker2=true;

       for(int positionCheck2 = 0; positionCheck2 < Diver2.length-1; 
           positionCheck2++){

          if(Diver2[positionCheck2] > Diver2[positionCheck2+1]){

               temp = Diver2[positionCheck2+1];

               Diver2[positionCheck2+1] = Diver2[positionCheck2];

               Diver2[1] = temp;
               checker2=false; 
          }
       }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Diver1));

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Diver2));
  }
 }
```

Comment: have you tried debugging to narrow down the problem? Write a test suite? At least indent the code so it's easier to look at.

Comment: If you step through this with a debugger, you will see immediately what's going on.

Comment: How would I use the debugger in eclipse to see what went wrong.

Comment: Set a breakpoint.  Step through the code.  Observe the program  flow.  Inspect any variables you need to inspect.  Same as you'd debug any other program.

Comment: @ThomasP Please see my answer, I just updated it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to always set the second position at Diver1 to be the temp variable?
 Because that is what you are doing by saying `Diver1[1] = temp`. Maybe try saying something like `Diver1[positionCheck2] = temp` instead. This applies to both of your spots that you are attempting the sort.

Also, I do not believe your bubble sort is a full bubble sort. It seems to only make one iteration over the array of numbers, bubbling the max value to the end of the array and then stopping. A full bubble sort would continue these iterations, moving the max element all the way to the end, then moving the second max element to the second spot from the end, then moving the third max element to the third spot from the end, etc. until sorted.

Update:
Your code is never reaching the print statements because it is getting stuck in your `while` loop. `while(checker==false)` continues to be false, so it never exists the loop. As I mentioned above, fix your "swap" and eventually this should resolve.